# Facebook Connect and then display user's first+last name and profile picture

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'd like new users to be able to 'connect' with the use of the fb connect button on my site and once connected it will display their first+last name and profile picture.

If the user is already connected, the connect button turns into a logout.

Going by the docs, i've implemented the following code;

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>test full name and photo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'xxxxxxxxxx', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
         FB.api('/me', function(user) {
           if(user != null) {
              var image = document.getElementById('image');
              image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
              var name = document.getElementById('name');
              name.innerHTML = user.name
           }
         });
       </script>
           <div align="center">
           <img id="image"/>
           <div id="name"></div>
           </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The only problem is that it does not display the facebook connect button and when I try and insert it, the code breaks.

Any help would be much appreciated!

recap: website checks if the user has connected and has a valid session, if not, display fb connect/login button, if yes, display the logout button, either way it should show the user their name and profile photo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) will do exactly what you want:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
// Session based API call.
if ($user) {
    try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
    }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>test full name and photo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>', // App ID
            channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
          window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    </script>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
      <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
    </a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div>
      Using JavaScript &amp; XFBML: <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>


    <?php if ($user): ?>
    <div align="center">
        <img id="image" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $uid; ?>/picture" />
        <div id="name"><?php echo $me['name']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```